# Complex number equals method

Tags: java, equals, complex-numbers

I'm making a complex number class in Java like this:

```
public class Complex {
    public final double real, imag;

    public Complex(double real, double imag) {
        this.real = real;
        this.imag = imag;
    }

    ... methods for arithmetic follow ...
}
```

I implemented the equals method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Complex) {
        Complex other = (Complex)obj;
        return (
            this.real == other.real &&
            this.imag == other.imag
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

But if you override equals, you're supposed to override hashCode too. One of the rules is:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Comparing `float`s and `double`s with `==` does a numeric comparison, so `+0.0 == -0.0` and NaN values are inequal to everything including themselves. So I tried implementing the hashCode method to match the equals method like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    long real = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.real); // harmonize NaN bit patterns
    long imag = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.imag);
    if (real == 1L << 63) real = 0; // convert -0.0 to +0.0
    if (imag == 1L << 63) imag = 0;
    long h = real ^ imag;
    return (int)h ^ (int)(h >>> 32);
}
```

But then I realized that this would work strangely in a hash map if either field is NaN, because `this.equals(this)` will always be false, but maybe that's not incorrect. On the other hand, I could do what `Double` and `Float` do, where the equals methods compare `+0.0 != -0.0`, but still harmonize the different NaN bit patterns, and let `NaN == NaN`, so then I get:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Complex) {
        Complex other = (Complex)obj;
        return (
            Double.doubleToLongBits(this.real) ==
                Double.doubleToLongBits(other.real) &&
            Double.doubleToLongBits(this.imag) ==
                Double.doubleToLongBits(other.imag)
        );
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    long h = (
        Double.doubleToLongBits(real) +
        Double.doubleToLongBits(imag)
    );
    return (int)h ^ (int)(h >>> 32);
}
```

But if I do that then my complex numbers don't behave like real numbers, where `+0.0 == -0.0`. But I don't really need to put my Complex numbers in hash maps anyway -- I just want to do the right thing, follow best practices, etc. And now I'm just confused. Can anyone advise me on the best way to proceed?

Comment: Note that `new Double(-0.0).equals(new Double(+0.0)) == false`. If you really care, you can check implement your own `doubleToLongBits` method that returns the same result for both zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about this some more. The problem stems from trying to balance two uses of equals: IEEE 754 arithmetic comparison and Object/hashtable comparison. For floating-point types, the two needs can never be satisfied at once due to NaN. The arithmetic comparison wants `NaN != NaN`, but the Object/hashtable comparison (equals method) requires `this.equals(this)`.

`Double` implements the methods correctly according to the contract of `Object`, so `NaN == NaN`. It also does `+0.0 != -0.0`. Both behaviors are the opposite from comparisons on primitive float/double types.

`java.util.Arrays.equals(double[], double[])` compares elements the same way as `Double` (`NaN == NaN`, `+0.0 != -0.0`).

`java.awt.geom.Point2D` does it technically wrong. Its equals method compares the coordinates with just `==`, so `this.equals(this)` can be false. Meanwhile, its hashCode method uses `doubleToLongBits`, so its hashCode can be different for two objects even when equals returns true. The doc makes no mention of the subtleties, which implies the issue is not important: people don't put these types of tuples in hash tables! (And it wouldn't be very effective if they did, because you'd have to get *exactly* the same numbers to get an equal key.)

In a tuple of floating-points like a complex number class, the simplest correct implementation of equals and hashCode is to **not** override them at all.
If you want the methods to take the value in account, then the correct thing to do is what `Double` does: use `doubleToLongBits` (or `floatToLongBits`) in both methods. If that's not suitable for arithmetic, a separate method is needed; perhaps `equals(Complex other, double epsilon)` to compare numbers for equality within a tolerance.

Note that you can override `equals(Complex other)` without interfering with `equals(Object other)`, but that seems too confusing.

Comment: My inclination would be to regard two doubles as equal if they report equal to each other, or if neither reports equal to itself.  I think defining `equals` in that fashion would yield an equivalence relation which `==` should have supported in the first place (it's not possible for any floating-point number system to uphold every axiom one might like, but having `==` and `!=` define an equivalence relation would be far more important than whatever is satisfied by having `NaN==NaN` return false and `NaN!=NaN` return true.

Answer (score 0):

The pathological case seems to be `0.0 != -0.0`, so I'd make sure that never happens and do the rest of the it exactly the way Joshua Bloch tells you in "Effective Java".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the hashCode contract guarantees that hashCodes equal if the objects equal, but not that hashcodes are different if the objects are different.  So you could just use this.real as the hash code, and accept the collisions.  Unless there is a priori knowledge about the distribution of the numbers your library will actually encounter, it may not be possible to do better: you have 128 bits of values, and 32 bits of hash, so collisions are inevitable (and harmless, unless you can show that they pessimize your lookups for expected data sets).